# Apple IPhone 5c does not allow incoming or outgoing calls

Tags: iphone

My IPhone doesn't allow incoming or outgoing phone calls. Starts to dial then just goes back to the contacts screen  I can receive messages and send messages BUT only to people with an Apple device. Please help.

Comment: Sounds like you need to contact your provider.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to try:

1. Try forcing it off (hold power button and home button down for
   10+ seconds) and back on.
2. Try removing and reseating the SIM.
3. Make a test call to customer service (611 in the US).
4. If none of the above work, you can reset network settings (Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Network Settings).

This is what any tech support (Apple Store, carrier) would have you do first.